# Windows Phone 7 ShareStatusTask - Is it possible to customize it further?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, twitter, windows-phone-7.1

```
ShareStatusTask statusTask = new ShareStatusTask();
statusTask.Status = "Blogging";
statusTask.Show();
```

There is a ShareStatusTask available in Windows Phone 7 which meets most of my needs. But I need to further customize it. Meaning, I have individual Facebook, Twitter, Live icons. When an user hits them, I should be able to popup the share status task with either Facebook or Twitter or Live pre-selected.

If they are not configured, I would show an error message probably to configure it in their device (under settings -> accounts).

Is there any code or inbuilt functionality available in Mango to access these ?

Comment: Hi, can you help me or show the way for this question mate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973578/how-to-share-my-news-on-facebook-on-windows-phone-8/17973782?noredirect=1#17973782

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way available to further customize it.

When you use ShareStatusTask (or some other similar tasks like ShareLinkTask), the control completely goes to the Operating System and we have nothing to do with.

If we really want to customize, we have to go for our own implementations using some third party libraries like [Hammock](http://nuget.org/packages/Hammock) or [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) for Twitter and [Facebook c# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) for facebook.

Even with a little disadvantage, I would suggest to use ShareStatusTask for simple implementations, unless you need some picture sharing etc.

Comment: Thanks for showing those libraries. Is there a way to at least know that whether a Facebook or twitter account is pre configured in the mobile device?