# How to Share My News on Facebook on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, facebook, twitter, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am on windows phone project. This project includes the latest news from various categories.

I'm done with getting news from my web service on my device. But i need to share these news on facebook, twitter etc..

How can i do that ?

I checked `https://developers.facebook.com/` but couldn't find the idea or i found, here `http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/`.

Is there any idea ? Help me about this please. I need to put a button at the end of my news and i need to share them on social platforms.

Waiting your answers with four-eye.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ShareStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharestatustask)

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //theMessageStatus is the message you want to post to FB/Twitter
   ShareNewsArticle(theMessageStatus);
}

private void ShareNewsArticle(string message)
{
   ShareStatusTask sst = new ShareStatusTask();
   sst.Status = message;
   sst.Show();
}
```

This will let the user choose what social network to update (e.g. FB, Twitter etc..)

Comment: Can you explain a little more please ? I'm new about this. I have a newsdetail.xaml page, i get the news article on that page, at the end of the article, should i put a share button and write your code (at answer) on button click of it ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you controlling the website? Or is this any website? If you're controlling it, then you can use the widgets FB/Twitter provides on your site itself. If it could be any site then you can use the ShareStatusTask. I've updated the answer that will hopefully clarify.

Comment: This is more clear thanks. By the way, I'm not controlling a website. I get the articles to my windows phone application by using my web service. I think I should get/bind the article on my newsdetail.xaml page. But how can i bind the article on that page to my button click.

Comment: If you want binding, then read up on MVVM (example http://yevgeller.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/simple-mvvm-tutorial-for-windows-phone.html). If you just want to get the message then it depends on what data your web service returns. If it just returns the string URL then set that as `theMessageStatus`, otherwise you might have to parse the data. Either way, this should be a new question that might need more details.

Comment: I get the Json data from my web service. There is no problem. I will just set the my article text as theMessageStatus then. I will try now and i will return answer here. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Depending on how complex JSON data/what you're doing with it, I recommend looking into JSON.NET (http://json.codeplex.com/). It's fast and makes it easy to access the values :)